# jquery select appended elements

Tags: jquery

Faced with a problem that jquery doesn't allow to select appended element. 
I've seen a lot of advices how to solve it. 
For example:

```
var $li = $('<li><span>' + html + '</span></li>');
$('.top').append($li);
```

But it can't help me in my way.
I get from server list of records from database in json format and in my view and I loop by this list and generate some html structure.

For example:

```
$.getJSON( "/searchbytype", data, function( data ) {
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        $('items').append('<li class="item">'+ val.name + '</li>');
    });
});
```

And what I want to do next is click on some `li` item and to do some manipulation. `Ul` list may contain 100-200 `li` tags. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: And which part is not working?

Comment: [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I should have looked for a duplicate before answering. Pretty sure there would be at least one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need event-delegation

```
$('body').on('click', 'li', function(){
   // this handler will work even for dynamically created <li>
});
```

Comment: So simple, thank you! But it started to work when I reordered li and click: $('body').on('click', 'li', function(){

Comment: @user3673623 ah! Yes, swapped both.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$.getJSON("/searchbytype", data, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        $('<li>', {
            class: 'item'
        }).html(val.name).on('click', function () {
            // Your code here.
        }).appendTo('.items');
    });
});
```

**Note:** I'm assuming the container is an element with `class` equals `items`, so I've added a missing `.` to prefix it in the `jQuery` selector.